# Travis build is hanging waiting for user input (To install angular)

Tags: angular, travis-ci

When building the app with Travis, the build hangs after it tries to install angular. It does this by waiting for input.

I have gone through the docs which show that this is indeed the case when "Waiting for keyboard input or other kind of human interaction". But I get no option of doing this anywhere. My  .travis.yml is up to date and does what is expected.

My .yml code

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "11.0"
sudo: required
branches:
  only:
    - master
before_script:
  - npm install -g --silent firebase-tools
  - npm install -g @angular/cli
script:
  - npm install
  - ng build --prod
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: firebase
  token:
    secure: "1/St7DD3G1QTmK-hdghJoK4cS348_bxklRqbuM3t7KGuE"

after_success:
  - firebase deploy --token "1/St7DD3G1QTmK-hdghJoK4cS348_bxklRqbuM3t7KGuE" --non-interactive
```

> Would you like to share anonymous usage data with the Angular Team at
>   Google under Google’s Privacy Policy at
>   https://policies.google.com/privacy? For more details  and how to
>   change this setting, see http://angular.io/analytics. (y/N)  No output
>   has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a
>   stalled build or something wrong with the build itself. Check the
>   details on how to adjust your build configuration on:
>   https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received
>   The build has been terminated

Comment: can you give your github repository link?

Comment: Here it is  https://github.com/Zupirio/ITS-structure/commit/747a708d352c37efa2f7d78f8fb89e36d1ffea49

Comment: It ended up working by itself with no input from my side. I did try to edit the .yml file which it didn't work in the beginning as well so *shrug* I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

You need add this in your `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_script:
  - export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=ci
```

You can find [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/bakery/blob/master/.travis.yml) a online sample ready for use.

Comment: It appears that this environment variable is actually documented in the analytics documentation file: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/design/analytics.md#disabling-usage-analytics (It also states that setting the env variable to `ci` will set analytics for CIs, but actually turns off analytics)

Answer (score 0):

Change in your Travis file

from: `npm install -g @angular/cli`
to: `es | npm install -g @angular/cli`

This sends one "yes" to the NPM install command.