# CircleCI build failed due to Google anonymous usage data question

Tags: angular, circleci

While CircleCI build, in the processes of executing `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` Google asked to share anonymous data usage yes/no question. How can I avoid prompt of that question in CircleCI ?

Image of docker is `circleci/node:8`
Command `run: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Error message:

> #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
>
> sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
>
> /usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng @angular/cli@8.0.1 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
> ? Would you like to share anonymous usage data with the Angular Team at Google under Google’s Privacy Policy at https://policies.google.com/privacy? For more details and how to change this setting, see http://angular.io/analytics. (y/N) ?
>
> Would you like to share anonymous usage data with the Angular Team at Google under Google’s Privacy Policy at https://policies.google.com/privacy? For more details and how to change this setting, see http://angular.io/analytics. (y/N) ?
>
> Would you like to share anonymous usage data with the Angular Team at Google under Google’s Privacy Policy at https://policies.google.com/privacy? For more details and how to change this setting, see http://angular.io/analytics. (y/N) Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s)

This question is about CircleCI build and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363203/travis-build-is-hanging-waiting-for-user-input-to-install-angular) is not a solution for me. I can't get this solution implemented in CircleCI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travis build is hanging waiting for user input (To install angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363203/travis-build-is-hanging-waiting-for-user-input-to-install-angular)

Comment: I believe not because it doesn't solve the issue. [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14619)

Comment: @halfer can you please remove the duplicate marker.

Comment: This looks like an _exact_ duplicate, Sasitha. Don't be put off by the fact that you're using Circle and the other one is for Travis - the error is the same, and I would expect the solution there to work too. If the issue is different (as per your answer) then would you edit the question to explain why it is different - did you try it?

Comment: Note that on Stack Overflow, claiming something is different does not make it different. Your additional note in the question says "it is not a solution" and that you "can't get it implemented" could do with some expansion (at least, if you want to help differentiate these questions).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can let your angular know that it's being built in CI by defining environmental variable `NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=ci`. Or just disable usage analytics question completely with `NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=false`.

Refer to [angular-cli/docs/design/analytics.md:Disabling Usage Analytics](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/design/analytics.md#disabling-usage-analytics) for more information.

Comment: It's the best solution. However in my project, I have specified which version of Angular to use. If version is below Angular 8 then all good. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by making few changes.

1. New angular-cli@8 does not support node@8. So I change my code to
   `npm install -g @angular/cli` to `npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9`
2. Also at the end of the line `> /dev/null` part was added.  `npm
   install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9 > /dev/null`