# CI can't build Angular 8 application

Tags: angular, continuous-integration

I'm trying to build my app via CI but it won't build since it shows a prompt asking for an answer (y/N) but I can't answer that. How am I supposed to deal with this?

> Would you like to share anonymous usage data with the Angular Team at
>   Google u nder Google’s Privacy Policy at
>   https://policies.google.com/privacy? For more details...

I've tried setting

"build": "set NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=ci && ng build"

on my package json but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travis build is hanging waiting for user input (To install angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363203/travis-build-is-hanging-waiting-for-user-input-to-install-angular)

Comment: Looks like you're installing the CLI before you do the build. You should only do `npm install && npm build`. npm will run `ng` from the `node_modules`.